# Sitecore Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, sitecore

We are going to use the Active Directory module to sync our users. We are still debating on whether to maintain roles within Sitecore or AD. We have had performance issues in a previous implementation of Sitecore when syncing with AD, so that makes us a little hesitant to have roles in AD. We will be creating an OU for users who need to be in Sitecore.

- What is the recommendation from Sitecore regarding users and roles and AD?
- Would keeping roles within Sitecore make sense and users in AD to see if that would make a difference in performance?
- If we decided to have roles within Sitecore now and then move to AD later, would that be possible? How would security on existing items be affected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance issues I have seen in the past with AD syncs were due to the query against AD returning vast amounts of data. I recommend you create a dedicated OU for security groups (and users if you are lucky enough that your organization can support this) related to Sitecore. Think of these security groups as Sitecore roles and assign AD users as members to these security groups accordingly.

On the Sitecore side, you should still use roles. Only, instead of assigned users from AD you will assign security groups to those roles.

This will allow you to continue to authorize groups of people in Sitecore per role, while delegating the task of maintaining individual membership to roles in AD where it typically should remain.

Answer (score 1):

In my implementations of the AD module, using indirect membership (role in role in role in role) has performance implications. If you have a direct membership (User A is in Role B) model, I have not seen many performance issues unless, as @Patrck Perrone mentioned, you are using filters that pull back a massive number of users.

My typical recommendation for folks who are not sure which direction to go with their security is to use AD groups to manage your users belonging to specific roles, and then map those AD groups as members of the Sitecore roles. In that way, you can secure all your content to Sitecore roles, and your users will automatically gain access via their AD group.

Example:

- **In Active Directory:** User Jay => Member of AD Group 'nonlinear\Sitecore Authors'
- **In Sitecore Roles:** 'nonlinear\Sitecore' is member of 'sitecore\Author'
- **In Sitecore content:** 'Home' item workflow secured to 'sitecore\Author'

In the above example, all users who are sitecore\Author members will be able to work on the Home page. User Jay, when added to the AD Group 'nonlinear\Sitecore Authors', will gain this access due to the relationship defined between the roles.

The benefit here is that if AD goes down, or you decide to stop using the AD roles, you don't have to re-apply security to your content. You would just start adding your AD users directly to sitecore\Author.

This is also helpful for local developers or offline developers working locally on their laptop who do cannot connect to the active directory repository. They can still setup all the content security and test with local Sitecore domain users while disconnected from AD.